# Why do we get low score with react-google-recaptcha-v3?

Tags: reactjs, recaptcha-v3

When verifing the recaptcha token in the background it returns a score of 0.1 almost everytime BUT not everytime. We have no clue why this is happening

Wrapper:

```
import React from "react";
import ContactInfo from "../components/Contact/ContactInfo";
import { GoogleReCaptchaProvider } from "react-google-recaptcha-v3";

const Contact = () => {
  return (
    <GoogleReCaptchaProvider
      reCaptchaKey="REMOVED"
      scriptProps={{
        async: false, // optional, default to false,
        defer: false, // optional, default to false
        appendTo: "head", // optional, default to "head", can be "head" or "body",
        nonce: undefined, // optional, default undefined
      }}
      container={{
        parameters: {
          badge: "bottomright", // optional, default undefined
          theme: "dark", // optional, default undefined
        },
      }}
    >
      <ContactForm />
    </GoogleReCaptchaProvider>
  );
};

export default Contact;
```

ContactForm:

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import { GoogleReCaptcha } from "react-google-recaptcha-v3";
import Button from "../UI/Button/Button";

const ContactForm = () => {
  const intialInput = {
    name: "",
    email: "",
    message: "",
  };

  const [token, setToken] = useState();
  const [userInput, setUserInput] = useState(intialInput);

  const inputChangeHandler = (input, value) => {
    setUserInput((prevState) => {
      return { ...prevState, [input]: value };
    });
  };

  const handleServerResponse = (ok, msg, form) => {
    if (ok) {
      setUserInput(intialInput);
    } else {
    }
  };

  const onVerify = useCallback((token) => {
    setToken(token);
  }, []);

  const handleOnSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const form = e.target;

    let data = {
      Name: userInput["name"],
      Email: userInput["email"],
      Message: userInput["message"],
      Token: token,
    };
    console.log(token, "Token:");
    fetch("https://HIDDEN/api/Email", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
      body: JSON.stringify(data),
    })
      .then((data) => {
        handleServerResponse(data.ok, data.statusText, form);
      })
      .catch((r) => {
        console.log(r);
        handleServerResponse(false, r, form);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Card>
      <div className={`${classes["container"]} container mt-2`}>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div className="row">
            <h4 className={`${classes["h4"]} mt-3`}>
              Kontakta oss via formulär
            </h4>
            <form onSubmit={handleOnSubmit} autoComplete="on">
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="Name">
                  Namn
                </label>
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="text"
                  id="Name"
                  autoComplete="on"
                  required
                  value={userInput["name"]}
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    inputChangeHandler("name", event.target.value)
                  }
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="Email">
                  E-post
                </label>
                <input
                  className="form-control"
                  type="email"
                  id="Email"
                  autoComplete="on"
                  required
                  value={userInput["email"]}
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    inputChangeHandler("email", event.target.value)
                  }
                />
              </div>
              <div className="mb-3">
                <label className="form-label" htmlFor="Message">
                  Meddelande
                </label>
                <textarea
                  className="form-control"
                  rows="5"
                  id="Message"
                  autoComplete="off"
                  required
                  value={userInput["message"]}
                  onChange={(event) =>
                    inputChangeHandler("message", event.target.value)
                  }
                />
              </div>
              <div className={` ${classes["style-1"]}`}>
                <Button className="button-full-width" type="submit">
                  Skicka
                </Button>
                <GoogleReCaptcha onVerify={onVerify} />
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default ContactForm;
```

Backend:  (lowered score check due to always failing if higher)

```
[HttpPost]
        public IActionResult SendEmail([FromBody] EmailDto request)
        {
            try
            {
                if (ReCaptchaPassed(request.Token ?? "false"))
                {
                    _emailService.SendEmail(request);
                    return Ok();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                return BadRequest(e.Message);
                
            }


            return this.StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity, "Invalid reCaptcha Token");
               
        }

        public static bool ReCaptchaPassed(string gRecaptchaResponse)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError(gRecaptchaResponse);
            string ReCaptchaSecretKey = "HIDDEN;
            HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

            var res = httpClient.GetAsync($"https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify?secret={ReCaptchaSecretKey}&response={gRecaptchaResponse}").Result;

            if (res.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                return false;
            }

            string JSONres = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            dynamic JSONdata = JObject.Parse(JSONres);

            try
            {
                double score = Convert.ToDouble(JSONdata.score);
                
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Score: " + score);
                if (JSONdata.success != "true" || score < 0.1) 
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

            return true;
        }
```